# Has the Catholic Church made a list of events in the life of Jesus which took place in fulfillment of prophecies of the Old Testament?

Tags: catholicism, life-of-jesus, prophecy, timetable

There appears to be a number of events in the life of Jesus which took place in order to fulfill one prophecy or other of the Old Testament, but are not specifically quoted as such by the evangelists.  For instance, the Gospels of Matthew (27:60), Mark (15:46 ) and Luke (23:53) narrate that  the Body of Jesus, after his crucifixion was laid in a tomb 'hewn in the rock'. One is able to comprehend the narrative after reading   Isaiah 53:9 (RSVCE):"And they made his grave with the wicked and with a rich man in his death..."

I would like to quote the above as an example of events which the evangelists did not explicitly state to have happened in fulfillment of  prophecies of OT. My question, therefore, is: has the Catholic Church made a list of events in the life of the Lord  which took place in fulfillment of prophecies of the OT and which in fact, were not mentioned as such by the evangelists  ?

Comment: I'm reasonably sure the brief answer would be No.

Comment: This question is answerable, but I am not sure one can find an internet source for you. Some monastic libraries should have what you are looking for.